# MVC2: How to connect to ODBC datasource

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-2

I have built an ASP.NET classic application that references an ODBC connection to a DBISAM database.

When I try to connect to the same database in a MVC2 application I do not see any option to select an ODBC Data Source.

1. I right-click on my Models folder and select Add -> New  Item
2. Choose "Data" on the left panel
3. Select ADO.NET Entity Data Model  than click "Add"

   ```
      Options were:

                        ADO.NET Entity Data Model

                        DataSet

                        LINQ to SQL Classes

                        SQL Server Database

                        XML File

                        XML Schema

                        XSLT File
   ```
4. Select "Generate from database..... click "Next"
5. Here I am presented with a "Choose Your Data Connection" screen.  When I click the "New Connection" button I am given a "Choose Data Source" screen.
6. I am only presented with the following options on the "Choose Data Source" screen:

Microsoft SQL Server

Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5

Microsoft SQL Server Database File

1. This is where I expected to see ODBC as one of my options.  What do I need to do to access ODBC?

Thank You for all help provided!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to connect to Oracle be sure to use the Oracle ODP, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: Without Data provider Is it possible to connect Oracle Database?

Comment: I have installed Oracle Data provider for Dotnet, How can i configure.